# Regex to Match String Syntax in Code

Tags: python, regex, escaping, syntax-highlighting

Let's say, for example, there is a Python source code file like:

```py
def someStuff():
  return "blabla"

myThing = "Bob told me: \"Hello there!\""

twoStrings = "first part " + "second part"
```

How would I write a regular expression to match:

`"blabla"`, `"Bob told me: \"Hello there!\""`, `"first part "`, & `"second part"`

including the surrounding quotes?

---

Originally, I figured this could be done simply with `\"[^\"]*\"` but this fails to take into account cases where the string contains a `\"`. I've tried incorporating negative look-behinds also:

`(?<!\\)\"[^\"]*(?<!\\)\"`

but have not had any success. What would be the recommended way to handle this?

Comment: Does it _have_ to be regex? There are better ways to extract string literals from python code.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Unfortunately, due to the library I'm relying upon, yes. Though, technically, I could rewrite the entire thing, but not unless I'm absolutely certain that would be required, which I don't think it would with how powerful regex can be, I REALLY don't want to.

Comment: Doing that with regexes you would have to deal with possible quotes inside `'''`, `r'`,  `' """ '`, etc. Do you think it's worth the effort? Or it's not your use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex (with single-line modifier `s`) should match all kinds of string literals:

```
([bruf]*)("""|'''|"|')(?:(?!\2)(?:\\.|[^\\]))*\2
```

This supports triple-quoted strings, escape sequences, and it also captures any prefixes like `r`, `u`, `f`, and `b`. See the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/e91qw5/2).

The single-line modifier `s` is required to correctly match multi-line strings. Additionally, enabling the `i` modifier makes it match capitalized prefixes like `R'nobody uses capitalized prefixes anyways'`.

---

As far as I'm aware, there are two caveats:

1. It also matches bytes literals.
2. It matches string literals in comments.

---

Explanation of the regex:

```
([bruf]*)          # match and capture any prefix characters
("""|'''|"|')      # match the opening quote
(?:                # as many times as possible...
    (?!\2)         # ...as long as there's no closing quote... 
    (?:            # ...match either...
        \\.        # ...a backslash and the character after it
    |              # ...or...
        [^\\]      # ...a single non-backslash character
    )        
)*
\2                 # match the closing quote
```

Comment: Did you design this regex yourself, or did you get it from another source? If so, may you share the source?

Comment: @Snusifer Wrote it myself.

Comment: Is there any way to also match multiline strings with all possible special characters?

Answer (score 1):

Use negative look behind:

[`".*?(?<!\\)"`](https://regex101.com/r/ve8OCQ/1)

This uses a lazy quantifier (`*?`) to match until the next quote (`"`) as long the quote is not escaped by a backslash (`\"`). Compare with the simpler (but erroneous) regex `".*?"`